# how to echo strings and variable simultaneously in laravel blade template engine?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using this code inside my PHP file:

**layout.blade.php**

```
{{ HTML::script('js/abc.js'); }}
```

The problem is `abc` will be different for different pages, so I need to change it to a variable (i.e. `$js`) to make the value dynamic.

Currently I am using:

`{{ HTML::script('js/'.$js.'.min.js') }}` to achieve this.

I was wondering whether this is the regular way to do this? Or is there any better way?

And I tried to use `{{ HTML::script('js/'.$js.'.min.js') or ''}}` to check the existence of `$js`, but it's not working. Is `@if (isset($js))` my only solution?

Thanks.

Comment: how is `$js` set? do you scan directories for this? or just simple string assignment?

Comment: @kevinabelita using `with` method in `routes.php` i.e. `->with('js', 'index')`

Answer (score 1):

The way that you are using `HTML::script` is not horrible, and it is an acceptable way of getting the job done!

I would however recommend using a Form macro, if for any other reason then it just looks nicer when reading the template, as I try to avoid using as little PHP as possible in my views.

Inside your `app/start.php` file, enter something like this:

```
 Form::macro('javascript_file', function($js = null) {
    if ($js === null) return;

    return HTML::script( 'js/'.$js.'.min.js');
 }
```

Then inside your templates you can just go:

```
@if isset($js)
{{ Form::javascript_file($js); }}
@endif
```

Sadly there is no way to check if $js is set before calling javascript_file without it looking more ugly...